# For and Implode Together

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I want to get the days in between a start and end date but the problem I'm facing is that it is not returning anything, even though I have dates in my database.

Basically, I want anything that has

```
04/20/2015
04/21/2015
04/22/2015
04/23/2015
04/24/2015
04/25/2015
04/26/2015
```

Here is my code:

```
//this gets days in between
$end = $enddate;//end date
$start = $gdate;//state date
$datediff = strtotime($end) - strtotime($start);
$datediff = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
for($i = 0; $i < $datediff + 1; $i++){
   $cole = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($start . ' + ' . $i . 'day')). ",";
}
echo $cole;
//gets all this 04/20/2015,04/21/2015,04/22/2015,04/23/2015,04/24/2015,04/25/2015,04/26/2015,

//sql command
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM `timesheet` WHERE `date` LIKE (" . implode(',', $cole) . ")";
```

Comment: why not just use a `BETWEEN` clause

Comment: Some of the dates don't exsit in the database so im just trying to get the ones that do

Comment: What do the date field values actually look like? Is it just a single date or are it multiple comma-separated dates like you're using in your comments?

Comment: The look like this Monday 03/30/2015 i think i might have to put Monday in a new column

Comment: i change the db so now the date column looks like this 03/30/2015 so im trying this out select * from `timesheet` where `date` between '03/30/2015' and '04/05/2015' but im only get one result i show be getting 4

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a more practical solution would be to do something like this:

```
//this gets days in between
$end = $enddate;//end date
$start = $gdate;//state date
$datediff = strtotime($end) - strtotime($start);
$datediff = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
// Make $cole an array so that it can be imploded.
$cole = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $datediff + 1; $i++){
  // Instead of one long string, add each $datediff to the $cole array
  // and surround each piece of the array with quotes:
  $cole[] = "'" . date("m/d/Y", strtotime($start . ' + ' . $i . 'day')). "'";
}
// Now you implode $cole and not have to worry about wrapping each value in quotes:
$cole_imploded = implode(',', $cole);
// It's also probably more practical to use "IN" for your MySQL query, like so:
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `timesheet` WHERE `date` IN (" . $cole_imploded . ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this simple solution.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `timesheet` WHERE `date` REGEXP '0?4\/2[0-6]\/2015$'";
```